# show input list on Notes web page with options taken from a view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to have a combobox on my Lotus Notes Page that I open in WEB...

```
  <input list="myList" name="myList">
  <datalist id="myList">
    <option value="item 1">
    <option value="item 2">
    <option value="item 3">
    <option value="item 4">
    <option value="item 5">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
```

as option values (list of items) I want to pull data from some Notes view.
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it (just one way)

```
<input list="myList" name="myList">
  <datalist id="myList">
    <computed text>  
  </datalist>
<input type="submit">
```

And **computed text** must have a formula (with [@DbColumn](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/f0a22f1e07b2507f85256c54004bf9d6?OpenDocument)) that generate options. This code just an example.
You will need to define view_name, column_number and possible database (if the view is in another database).

```
_col := @DbColumn(""; ""; "All"; 2);
_options := "<option value=\""+_col+"\">";
@Implode(_options; @NewLine)
```

[image]

Here is a result (my view has only 2 values, 'index' and 'test'):

[image]

Also keep in mind that there is a limit (64Kb if I remember correctly) for result of @dbcolumn.

Comment: Thank you Dmytro.. I know I cannot use Notes fields on the page but just forgot about computed text.. 
Thank works.. thank you again

Comment: There's also a much shorter limit than 64K in a computed text element (4K IIRC); if there's any chance you could run into it, a computed-for-display field will do the same trick with a much larger data limit.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a more advanced solution, if you want a fancy combobox.
Use a jQuery plugin that support Ajax/JSON for the choices, and then create a Lotusscript agent on the server that return the values.

If you look at [this presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/559gc4h81f0den3/MWLUG_2015.pdf?dl=0) you perhaps get some ideas.

I have used that method in some applications, you get nice features like type-ahead, sorting and much more for free there.